# Since 10.11.1 Mail spends most of the time unable to connect to servers

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

After years of working smoothly, through many OS updates, including 10.11.0, my Apple Mail client now only succeeds in connecting to servers intermittently since updating to 10.11.1. I'd estimate that on a typical day, it manages to work about 10% of the time it is running. Mostly I just quit and leave the app closed to avoid the annoyance of constant warning dialogs interrupting me while I'm working. (Connection Doctor never shows any errors or difficulties.)

Is there something simple I might do to fix this? Is this a known problem with 10.11.**1**?

Comment: FWIW, the same collection of e-mail accounts works fine on iOS 9 Mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if you have [`_mbsetupuser` running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391174/656912). If you do your update to 10.11.1 (or to 10.11.2 or 10.11.3, for that matter) has not completed.

Though the "About This Mac" dialog may say that your version is 10.11.1, you are in fact effectively *between versions*, and will get all kinds of odd behavior (repeated requests to unlock the Keychain, connectivity problems, wifi issues, etc.) until you complete the installation process, which you should be able to accomplish with a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into this issue after an update from 10.11.x to 10.12.

When SSH'ing into the server as admin I would actually be the _mbsetupuser account every other time.

Every other time I tried to connect via ARD I would be denied access.

A reboot did *not* fix the issue for me.

I had to create a new admin account in system preferences, log in as that admin, delete the old admin account, and recreate it.